# Scatterplot with geom_text - showing subsample of labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running the following R Code with ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(result, aes(x=X2015, y=CPI.2015, color=Region)) + 
    geom_point(size=6, alpha=0.6)  +
    geom_text(aes(label=Country), size=3,color = "black")
   #scale_x_discrete(breaks=seq(0,1000, 200))
```

However, I get the following problems:

[result plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2Im3.png)

1. The x axis is completely unreadable. I have that line in my code (commented out) as above, but I get this "discrete value to continous scale" error.
2. I do not want to show ALL names, just some of them, to make it readable. Is that actually possible?

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example with `dput(result)`.

Comment: Can you give a sample of `result`?

Comment: Try with `dput(result[1:20,])`

Comment: structure(list(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", ...), Region = structure(c(2L, 3L, ...), .Label = c("AME", "AP", ...), class = "factor"), X2015 = c("479", "764",...), CPI.2015 = c(11, 36,...)), .Names = c("Country", "Region", "X2015", "CPI.2015"
), row.names = c(NA, -153L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Is it ok like that? Left for all kind of values 2 examples

Comment: Ok, I understood. The scale problem was, because one column wasn't numerical, but a character. BUt what about the names problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without original data it's hard to adjust parameters, but please try this:

Convert `X2015` to numeric:

```
result$X2015 <- as.numeric(result$X2015)
```

Randomly sample labels for `geom_text`:

```
# Number of labels to show
nOfLabels <- 10
result$Country2 <- ifelse(1:nrow(result) %in% sample(1:nrow(result), nOfLabels), 
                          result$Country, "")
```

Here I randomly sample 10 countries and for rest return empty string `""`.

And plot your `result` using:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(result, aes(X2015, CPI.2015, color = Region)) + 
    geom_point(size = 6, alpha = 0.6)  +
    geom_text(aes(label = Country2), size = 3,color = "black") +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(0, 1000, 200))
```

Comment: 'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL

Comment: is what I get for the codeline, where you insert either the name or ""